# Charting controls unavailable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am just getting started on chart controls and started with this technet article. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489237.aspx
Unfortunately, in spite of having chosen the required namespaces the chart control does not show up in the toolbox under data.
Am I missing something?

Comment: http://aspnetnova.blogspot.com/2009/01/installing-ms-chart-adding-into-vs-2008.html Have you done this? Should work on 2010 as well.

Comment: @Loktar Should not be required for 2010, should it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still using webforms are we? You could just save yourself a lot of hassle and just use a javascript solution like this, your server will definately love you for it.

http://www.highcharts.com/

I've had a lot of good luck with this solution, it does mean uderstanding javascript but its not rocket science.

Comment: I might need to be a lot more specific here. I am actually trying to get familiar with charting controls available straight from Visual Studio 2010 as my actual implementation would be to use them in building a custom web part for a sharepoint environment. Would you still recommend this? Thanks